# How to set Task Scheduler in Laravel to run only once at given timestamp?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, task, scheduled-tasks

How do I execute a function at a specific timestamp only once instead of making it run periodically?

Here is my application:
I have a table with 2 rows: id(primary key) and time(epoch timestamp stored as integer). Now, for each of the entries I want to call a function that will execute at the timestamp stored in table. How do I achieve this?

Are there any better alternatives to Task Scheduler? 
I'm using Laravel 5.4 (if it matters)

EDIT: I do know a workaround, but I am looking for most efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is to run the scheduler every minute and you select the records on that time period & execute the function. With the assumption the seconds doesn't matter I wrote the below code. If the seconds matters, you have to check how to run the scheduler every seconds, but the concept is same.

Hope this will help you

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
...
$schedule->call(function() {

    // Look in your table for `time` in current minute, between 0-59s
    $entries = TheTable::where([
        ['time', '>=', Carbon::now()->second(0)->timestamp],
        ['time', '<=', Carbon::now()->second(59)->timestamp]
    ]);

    // Loop through the results & call the function

})->everyMinute();
```

Comment: Yes, this does solve my problem. In fact, this was the first thing that came to my mind. But it's rather inefficient. It makes database query calls every minute.Even after my task is complete, it will keep running. Isn't there any better alternative? If not, I will have to make do with this trick.

Comment: Why not cache the response? That way it will only have to access the database once. If you need to run it again you can either set a timeout for the cache or clear it based on an appropriate event.